# Enable and Disable Task History

Tags: c#

I can able to get the history of the task, and can get the details of the task using the below code,

```
public void gethistory()
    {
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            TaskEventLog log = new 
            TaskEventLog("path");
            List<ListViewItem> c = new List<ListViewItem>(100);

           foreach (TaskEvent item in log)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Level);
                Console.WriteLine(item.TimeCreated);
                Console.WriteLine(item.EventId);
                Console.WriteLine(item.TaskCategory);
                Console.WriteLine(item.OpCode);
                Console.WriteLine(item.ActivityId);
            }
        }
    }
```

But my question is how to enable or disable the task's history in c#.net?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enable or disable history for individual tasks. The setting is global for all tasks in Task Scheduler.

You can enable or disable history for *all* tasks, using the `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` namespace, as the setting the Task Scheduler is just a proxy for the event log setting for it.

For example:

```
EventLogConfiguration config =
    new EventLogConfiguration("Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational");

config.IsEnabled = true;
config.SaveChanges();
```

Of course, set to `false` to disable again.